Unable to rewrite URL on IIS, getting 404.4 error
I'm encountering an issue with IIS where I'm unable to rewrite URLs. I have proxy enabled, and my SSL certificate is working correctly. and I'm pretty sure I have all the necessary modules installed. I even tried reinstalling the rewrite module with no avail..
Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Below are screenshots of the error and my config file.
Thank you,



You cannot merely copy the contents from your ServerFault post here, or it will be closed quickly as off topic. Instead, please show the relevant code snippets so that other programmers might see how ASP.NET routing rules were configured and that might explain why the specific handler returns 404.4, as long as you are hosting an ASP.NET web app. If you are hosting another stack, like Node.js, edit the question to include more details.

The error message states that this is a handler error. In web server speak, a "handler" is an additional step that the web server needs to wait for before it can pass the requested resource back to the client.
For example, when requesting a dynamic file, like an ASP file, PHP file, etc, the "handler" would be the language interpreter, which produces HTML and returns it back to the web server to pass back to the client. In this case, you're requesting a file that IIS doesn't know how to handle.
So, either you're rewriting the request to ask for a file that the web server doesn't know how to handle, or your original request is for a file that the server doesn't know how to handle.
Can't know which without more specifics. ;)
